# Gap between the double horizontal line wrapping a text

Tags: html, css

This is what I have right now but I need to adjust the gap of the two lines **on the header** with each other so it may look like the horizontal rule at the bottom.

Thing is when I adjust it at make it `border-top: 5px double black;`, it makes the lines thick when I need it to only be separated more and keep it thin.

Here's my HTML:

```
<h4><span>Sample sample sample</span></h4>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<hr>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
h4 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 4px double black;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin: 30px 0;
    font-size: 29px;

    span {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
}

hr {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
    border-top: 1.5px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    height: 10px;
}
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suika/nrEfm/69/) for it.

Comment: The tagged duplicate only needs a single line - it's not the same as the issue here.

Comment: It is...you can style the pseudo-elements any way you want. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/a157c0c8a3e616480177812c9c433808

Comment: Oh, you're right. I tried to make the border to `double` to give it a shot. How does duplicate questions work anyway? Do I have to take it down? Do you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Nope, just leave it as it is. It's fine. Now that 's it marked as a duplicate it can act as a pointer to future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove one border from this:

```
hr {
    /* border-bottom: 1.5px solid black; */
    border-top: 1.5px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    height: 10px;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anh7qtd1/**

Comment: Sorry no I need the header lines to be the same as the footer lines. I need to increase the gap of the lines with each other on the top.

Comment: @Suika Wait, you are confusing me. You want a border for the heading, and one for the footer right?

Comment: @Suika Do me a favour. Show me a image or sample of what you wanna achieve. Will you?

Comment: It's already on the fiddle. See the styling of the lines for the `<hr>`? I need that to be applied to `<h4>` as well because right now they are TOO CLOSE to each other when I need them as apart as the lines on the `<hr>` is. The lines below the Lorem Ipsum are what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Suika I said you in simple terms, I am unable to understand what you want. Can you do it in Paint or someway, show me an image of what you want? So that it is easy for us. Deal? `:)`